# Oracle parsing string for separators

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have one table in Oracle 11g database

I am storing some value like '|' separated mode as below

Table: **ABC**
FIELD: **XYZ**

Values :

```
9
1|12
52
5|112
```

Now I want to find `ID` from those values

I used `REGEXP_LIKE` but it will get all the rows containing value

Suppose I will search for 5 then it will give result for '5' and also for '52'

please help me to search particulate id from this field

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for rectifying

Comment: You shouldn't be storing delimited values in a single column. Think about normalizing your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
select * from table_name
 where '|' || column_name || '|' like '%|' || 'search_string' || '|%';
```

Sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e05a3/3).